# Forcing and justification

Tags: set-theory, multiverse, justification

In ["The set-theoretic multiverse,"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4223) Hamkins talks about forcing giving us "glimpses" of other set-theoretic universes. He states his position as a Platonistic one, i.e. these "glimpses" are functionally equivalent to "perceptions" of actual objects.

In ["The modal logic of forcing,"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509616), Hamkins (and Loewe) effectively claim that "is forceable" can mean "is possible." Now it seems that we can *also* say that "is forceable" can mean "is justifiable," for Hamkins, if we assume that "perceptions" of the states of affairs in a set-theoretic universe count as justifications of propositions about the contents of that universe. E.g. if we can force 2<sup>ℵ<sub>1</sub></sup> = ℵ<sub>29</sub>, then we are justified in proposing that there is a universe where 2<sup>ℵ<sub>1</sub></sup> = ℵ<sub>29</sub>.

My question is as follows. Let "**J**A" mean "it is justified that A" and "A →<sub>F</sub> B" mean "A is forced to B." (We assume that what is forced is an answer to a question, e.g., "CH or ~CH?" Otherwise we would say something like, "CH is forced to ~CH," which sounds wrong.) Now, on my reconstruction of Hamkins' viewpoint, does it make sense to say that we not only force sentences like, "A = B," but, "**J**(A = B)"? Moreover, then, what about, "**J**(A →<sub>F</sub> B)"? I.e. can forcings themselves be justified?†

†<sub>One might say that a forcing sentence is justified if it "works." But Hamkins says that even granting a plurality of worlds, we do not necessarily grant that these worlds are on a par. The unique value of CH might be that it requires the minimum justification out of all proposed values for the Continuum. It is forcing-possible and forcing-justifiable; but consider then, "**J**(A →<sub>F</sub> **J**(CH)," i.e. is it justifiable to force the sentence, "CH is justified"? If so, if *uniquely* so—if this sentence, which requires minimal justification, is then maximally justified!—have we gotten an answer to CH while keeping Hamkins' multiverse, too?</sub>

Comment: I don't understand your distinction between justifiability and forceability (especially given your second paragraph). But note that "forcing is transitive:" if V[G][H] is a generic extension of V[G] which is a generic extension of V, then V[G][H] is a generic extension of V (we have V[G][H]=V[GxH], and GxH will be generic over V for an appropriate iterated forcing). So "you can force the forceability of P" is equivalent to "P is forceable."

Comment: The interesting "multiple modality" statements are those which mix forceability with *non-forceability*: e.g. "there is a forcing extension W of V which has no forcing extension satisfying P." Some choices of P do give rise to principles of this form (e.g. "There is a real which is Cohen-generic over L"), while others don't (e.g. either of CH or ~CH).

Comment: Please, Hawkins is not a philosopher nor is he recognized as such.